# How to avoid redundant entries in legend using ggplot and patchwork?

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I am combining ggplots using the patchwork library and I am wondering if there is a way to eliminate redundant color entries for error bars and points. See and example using `mtcars` below.

```
# load data and libs
data("mtcars")

library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,hp,color = factor(am),size = wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  
ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,hp,color = factor(am),shape = factor(gear))) +
  geom_point() +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]

This produces a graph with a single legend entry for colors. However when I add error bars to one of the graphs:

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,hp,color = factor(am),size = wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  
ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,hp,color = factor(am),shape = factor(gear))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin = mpg-(mpg*0.2),
                    xmax =mpg+(mpg*0.2))) +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]

Now I get one legend for point color and a redundant error bar color label. I would like just one label for color. Is there anyway to get just a single color entry in the legend without dropping shape or size from the legend?

Comment: For those that are in reduced operating environments, the only thing `library(tidyverse)` is being used for here is `%>%`, which can be completely obviated by changing `mtcars %>% ggplot(..)` to `ggplot(mtcars, ..)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to remove "%>%" for simplicity @r2evans. The code is not abridged, "+" is used to add plots together in patchwork.

Comment: Yes, I know that `patchwork` makes `+`-ing them the trick. I cannot reproduce now, of course, but when I ran your code before, I got a parsing error. Bummer, thanks for your patience :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Legends will only get collected when they are identical. Hence, if you want only one color legend you have to make them identical which as one option could be achieved by adding `show.legend=FALSE` to `geom_errorbar`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- mtcars |> 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, hp, color = factor(am), size = wt)) +
  geom_point()

p2 <- mtcars |> 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, hp, color = factor(am), shape = factor(gear))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(
    xmin = mpg - (mpg * 0.2),
    xmax = mpg + (mpg * 0.2)
  ), show.legend = FALSE)

p1 + p2 +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]

Comment: Good approach. I was going down the path of attempting to "add" some empty aesthetics to the first plot so that the two color guides were close enough to be just one (and I could not find a way).

Comment: Thanks stefan! Simple enough to implement.

Comment: @r2evans Yeah. Something like fiddling with aesthetics was my first thought too before I realized that for the present case a simple `show.legend=FALSE` will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are after:

```r
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(mpg,hp,color = factor(am),size = wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  
  mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(mpg,hp,color = factor(am), shape = factor(gear))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin = mpg-(mpg*0.2),
                    xmax =mpg+(mpg*0.2)), show.legend = F) + ## Just turn off the legend for geom_errorbar
  plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

Comment: Thanks Matt! Yes this appears to solve it.

Comment: When you posted this answer, did you see that stefan had posted this trick almost 11 minutes prior?

Comment: @r2evans, no I am sorry. I refreshed before, started to code it and when finish posting then I saw the other answer.